# Hiding URL in code using ProGuard

Tags: java, android

I have a URL code in my Java class. I am using ProGuard in Android Studio this way. But, when I extract the apk back, I see that the URL is still visible. How can I hide the URL in my Android code for security measures?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 26
        versionName "1.25"
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'}
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.*
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
```

Comment: If proguard obfuscated a string you wouldn't be able to get to the original string in your code. Your best bet is to obscure the string yourself (encrypt) and unobscure it when you need it (decrypt). At the end of the day, though, anyone who really wants to find the URL will be able to.

Comment: Isn't the whole concept of proguard to stop users from decompiling and reverse engineering your app?

Comment: it isnt only concept, it doesnt do the job perfectly. Its goal is also to minify the application size. I am able to decompile using dex2jar , and see my urls in java classes.